# `rsync` during streaming

Tags: rsync

This question is essentially because of my inexperience using `rsync`, if it is duplicated i will promptly delete it.

I have a `/dir-scr` local folder, being fed continuously with production data from sensors readings. Every 10 minutes approx. a file with timestamp filename `yyyymmddhhmmss.dat` is being created, filled from 0 to 40MB approx. and closed. After 10 minutes approx., another file is created.

I've performed several batch executions of the updates:

```
$ rsync -azvP /dir-src/* host-dst:dir-src/
```

Which successfully copies and replaces partially filled files, i.e. copies complete files with 40MB and the current file with, let's say, 25MB, and at the next update, replace the 25MB file with the completed version with 40MB.

Currently I make a manual move operation for not deleting mistakenly any file not already copied.

Now i want to use one of the `rsync` flags such as:

- `--exclude`
- `--delete-excluded`
- `--delete-after`
- `--remove-source-files`

but i am unsure of their operation.

Question is, how to use `rsync` for moving files, let's say, older than 10 minutes, and delete from `/dir-src` if and only if they are already on `host-dst:dir-dst/`.

Comment: If you are looking to remove files from source after they have been sync'd, you need the `--remove-source-files` option. The `--delete` options deal with removing files at the destination that do not exist at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using rsyncs built in deletion options is **not the right way** to solve this problem.
If you do something like the following:

```
$ rsync -azvP --remove-source-files /dir-src/* host-dst:dir-src/
```

you could be left in the situation where rsync transfers a partially filled file and then deletes it. If the file gets recreated with the same name then rsync will overwrite the copy on the destination machine. Thus, you will lose the first half of the file.

Maybe you want to consider this instead. Let rsync do its transfer as normal, then you can set up a [cronjob](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) that runs every ten minutes and does something like this.

```
$ find /dir-src -type f -mmin +15 -exec rm -f {} +
```

This will find all files under the `dir-src` directory that are older than 15 minutes and delete them. We are assuming here that the maximum time that it takes for a file to be filled is 15 minutes. You may want to tweak this value to suit your needs. Also, while testing please replace `-exec rm -f {} +` with `-print`, this will ensure that find is only picking up the files you actually want to delete before performing any destructive operation.

In your comment you say you have an unreliable network connection and are worried that rsync may not complete successfully. One method to get around this could be the following after creating an auxiliary directory:

1. Every 15 minutes, move all files older than 15 minutes from `dir-src` to `dir-aux`.
2. Every 10 minutes, rsync files from `dir-aux` to `host-dst:dir-src`.
3. Every 60 minutes, delete all files in `dir-aux`.

This will ensure that rsync has had a chance to run 5-6 times before files are deleted. Depending on your connection this is probably enough. You can then scale that 60 minutes up or down depending on results from your testing.

Comment: My major fear is when trying to automate this, it is completely likely to loss connection onto the `dir-src` and there should be checking if the `rsync` was or not was executed succesfully the last time, hence every run of a `rm` command will be risky. So i can safely suppose not 15 mins, but maybe 1 hour, or more, but passing the full control to `rsync` for all those files, so that the current streaming is never interfered. My second choice actually is doing an executable, passing the files, listing the files and comparing them. I am sure there is a better way than that...

Comment: Or perhaps moving locally the files to a `dir-aux` folder with `mv`, for these older than 15 mins and then apply `rsync` on that folder?

Comment: I would go for your last solution if in your system `mv` (rename function) is atomic.

Comment: If your question has been answered please feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I will check the `mv` command perhaps today

Comment: Not the solution i expected, but thanks for your effort.